# How to use TFVC in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

I want to use and work with TFS in VS Code instead of Git. How can I do this?
I searched the old methods on the internet and Google, but I did not get any results.

I used the TFS plugin in VS Code but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control), the other kind of version control supported by Team Foundation Server (TFS) and Azure DevOps.

Support for TFVC has been removed from the Azure Repos extension for Azure DevOps a long time ago. [With that the whole Azure Reops extension for VsCode was archived](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-repos-vscode).

For TFVC you'll need to install a full version of Visual Studio Team Explorer or [use the command line instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=azure-devops).

A few folks have forked the old [Azure Repos extension and it can be found here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=argutec.argutec-azure-repos). You still need Team explorer or Team Explorer Everywhere installed alongside the extension. This extension hasn't been updated in 3 years though. Looking at the number of open security vulnerabilities (69) in its dependency tree I would not recommend using it.

[image]

After enabling code scanning on GitHub I'm even more convinced not to touch this extension anymore:

[image]

Comment: tanks for answer.
how to work TFS with command line?

Comment: There is a commandline utility that's installed with Team Explorer and Visual Studio. It's called `tf`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=azure-devops